# Counting Rows with Condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, rows

My pandas dataframe looks like following:

```
  a b c d e 
x 2 4 5 0 0
y 0 3 8 9 0
z 2 3 5 0 1
```

I want to count the rows where values != 0. I have tried this one but the output doesn't like what I expected :

```
df.sum(axis=1)
x 11
y 20
z 11
```

The output that I expected:

```
x 3
y 3
z 4
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out the 0 by using `.ne()` which is equivalent of `!=` and sum on axis=1, Use:

```
df.ne(0).sum(axis=1)
#alternatively (df!=0).sum(axis=1)

x    3
y    3
z    4
```